# Unable to close and save editor in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cant close or save any untitled or new editors that i have pasted some text in.
I have tried short cut keys, close all button, click on the close button of the editor, all of these are not working also.

But i am able to close other text file that i have already saved on disk.

I tried to update, relaunch the app, restart my laptop. It still happens.

I can't seems to find any similar issue and are at a lost here.